# how to create OAuth 2 token for Firebase push notifications V1 API with .NET8 C# on Windows?

Tags: c#, firebase, oauth-2.0, push-notification

The following .NET8 console application attempts to send a push using Firebase's new V1 API.

I create a Firebase JWT bearer token from the Firebase console generated configuration.json file that contains:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myProject",
  "private_key_id": "my private key id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n  DATA \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-XXXX.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "999999999999",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

It's failing when it attempts to send the request.  It returns:

```
{
   "error": {
       "code": 401,
       "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
       "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
   }
}
```

I can see in Visual Studio that the token returned from GetJwtToken is a valid JWT token with an hour before it expires.

What obvious mistake am I making?  Am I mistaken that it wants a JWT token?

Is there a Firebase routine that will give me the 'OUath 2 access token' it seems to expect?

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using RestSharp;

class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {

        // Send notification
        await SendNotificationAsync();
    }


    public static async Task SendNotificationAsync() {

        const string kMyToken = "myToken";

        // Get JWT token
        var bearerToken = await GetJwtToken();

        // Create client
        var client = new RestClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1");

        // Create request
        var request = new RestRequest("projects/myProject/messages:send", Method.Post);

        // Set auth header
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);

        // Set content type
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Construct notification payload
        var payload = new {
            message = new {
                token = kMyToken,
                notification = new {
                    title = "Test Title",
                    subtitle = "Test Sub-title",
                    body = "Test body.",
                    content_available = true
                },
                data = new {
                    key_1 = "posJob",
                    key_2 = "Value for key_2"
                }
            }
        };

        // Add payload to request
        request.AddJsonBody(payload);
        
        // Send request
        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    }

    public static async Task<string> GetJwtToken() {
        try {
            // Read credentials file
            var json = File.ReadAllText("credentials.json");

            // Parse JSON credentials
            var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json);

            var scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
            var accessToken = await credentials.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(scopes);

            return accessToken;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```